# Entity Framework Object contains same object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
public class ProjectPage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ProjectPageType Type { get; set; }

    public Guid? HeaderId { get; set; }
    public ProjectPage Header { get; set; }

    public Guid? FooterId { get; set; }
    public ProjectPage Footer { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to make this relation in Entity Framework code first? What can I write on model creating, to make it work? Now I have:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectPage>().HasOptional(p => p.Header);
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectPage>().HasOptional(p => p.Footer);
```

But it is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the foreign key:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectPage>()
             .HasOptional(e => e.Header)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(m => m.HeaderId);

 modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectPage>().
             .HasOptional(e => e.Footer)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(m => m.FooterId);
```